# Django REST Framework - can't override list in ListAPIView

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework to create an endpoint that will produce a PDF document. The PDF document will have information that corresponds to a particular `Department`. I have two desired functionalities -- to be able to download a PDF document, and to be able to preview the document within the browser.

Since the PDF document changes over time based on data that is added to the app, the document needs to be generated in real time when it is requested. As a first step, I'm trying to have the document be generated in a remote file storage location when the following endpoint is hit by a `GET` request:

`departments/<department_pk>/result/preview`

Since my endpoint should only take `GET` requests, I am using a `ListAPIView`. I'm trying to override the `list` method so that my custom document generation logic is executed, but it looks like the method is never called. How can I have some custom document generation logic be inserted into my endpoint, so that it is executed when the endpoint is hit by a `GET` request?

api/urls.py

```
url(r'^departments/(?P<department_pk>[0-9]+)/result/preview',
    include(result_document_urls.result_document_preview_router.urls,
```

document_app/urls.py

```
result_document_preview_router = routers.DefaultRouter()

result_document_preview_router.register(r'^', ResultDocumentDetailView.as_view(),
    base_name='Department')
```

document_app/views.py

```
class ResultDocumentDetailView(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = Department.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'department_pk'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'department_pk'

    def list(self, request, department_pk):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() # this break point is never hit
        department = get_object_or_404(queryset, department_pk=department_pk)
        ...generate document logic...
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: It seems to me you should be using a `RetrieveAPIView`. `ListAPIView` is for returning a collection. `Retrieve...` is for getting one instance. This being said, I don't see why `list` would not be called anyway.

Comment: @louis yeah, doesn't make sense to me either. I was originally using `RetrieveAPIView` but switched to `ListAPIView` because I wasn't sure whether I needed a `pk` at the end of my URL for `RetrieveAPIView`, and perhaps that was why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `document_app/urls.py`, you are incorrectly passing `ResultDocumentDetailView` as an argument instead of a viewset.

**Router [while registering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage) accepts a `ViewSet` instead of an `APIView`.**

> There are two mandatory arguments to the `register()` method:
>
> `prefix` - The URL prefix to use for this set of routes.
>   `viewset` - The **viewset class**.

Also, since you are only interested in the `retrieve` method, you can just create a `ResultDocumentRetrieveView` and add its corresponding url to your `urls.py` without the need of creating a `ResultDocument` router. (Routers are generally used when you want to handle both `list` and `detail` requests.)

```
class ResultDocumentRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    queryset = Department.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'department_pk'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'department_pk'

    def retrieve(self, request, department_pk):
        department = self.get_object()
        ...generate document logic...    
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^departments/(?P<department_pk>[0-9]+)/result/preview', ResultDocumentRetrieveView.as_view())
```

Answer (score 2):

replace list method with below code, I think it will work

```
class ResultDocumentDetailView(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = Department.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'department_pk'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'department_pk'

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() # this break point is never hit
        department = get_object_or_404(
            queryset, department_pk=kwargs.get('department_pk')
        )

        ...generate document logic...

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

for more reference see the overrinding method "list"

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L35

Comment: Hmm not too sure how this is different from the example code I gave out? Minus the indentation, which seems to be off. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: @orange1  you are not defining the method "list" correctly.  the correct definition is  " def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs): " .  did you try ? It will work.